# Reading/Writing files from\to Buffers

Tags: c++, file, buffer, binary-data

Simply I have a text file which contains binary numbers. I need to read these numbers (without converting to integers or ASCII) and store them properly in an unsigned char Buf. After processing these data on an electronic board, a method reads the output from the board and store it in a Buf as well. So, I also need to write the data from the Buf to an output file.

first, I have doubt about the size of the buffer. The declaration is as shown bellow:

```
#define Buff_size (long) 255;
unsigned char buf[Buff_size];
```

- What does 255  represent here? bits, bytes or words of unsigned char?
- My data size is: 2048 (number) * 32 (bits) = 65536 bits. However, the size of the input data file is 68 
  KB. Which size is actually the data size and I should use as the buffer size?

I have tried some codes, and I can run the full code with no errors. however, when I print out the buffer I get incorrect data. This is the declaration of the input\output files:

```
// Open input and output files.
f_in.open(infilename, std::ios::out);
if (false == f_in.is_open()) {
    printf("Error: Input file could not be opened.\n");
    return(false);
}
f_out.open(outfilename, std::ios::in);
if (false == f_out.is_open()) {
    printf("Error: Output file could not be opened.\n");
    return(false);
}
```

I tried to read the input data from the input file f_in using the two following commands:

```
1) f_in.read((char*)buf, Buff_size);
2) //f_in >> buf;
```

When I tried to read the buf as: `cout << buf << endl;` I got the correct data with some dummy data at the end using the first reading command. I'm assuming the size of the buffer is not approperate so I get these dummy data (very strange random characters). When I use the second command I get only first line of the input data file is printed out.

To summarise I need to read some data from a text file and store it in a buffer. Then write the output data line by line into an output file.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your input file looks like? Your description is confusing and seems to contradict itself.

Comment: my input looks like this:
00000000001000101101010110111011

00000000001000101101010110111011
00000000000101110011100100100111
00000000001000101101010110111011
00000000000101110011100100100111
00000000001000101101010110111011
00000000001000101101010110111011
00000000000101110011100100100111
00000000001000101101010110111011
one number (32 bits) in a line.

Comment: If your numbers are 32 bits in length then how are you going to store them in an 8 bit unsigned char? Since they are text the size of the data in the file is 32 bytes per number which may help you understand the apparent size difference between bits and bytes. It still isn't exactly clear what your goal is.

Comment: OK then what each digit will be stored as 8 bits because the data is read as text, right? Can you tell me which part is not clear to you so I can explain it more? I need to do a USB communication with a board to test some hardware. I need to feed the input as binary to the board then reads its output and store it on an output file. The input and output data should be binary numbers. the libraries I'm using for the USB communications use unsigned char buffer as a variable to store the data to be sent to the board and output data from the board.

Comment: So, my goal is to read these binary data correctly and store them on the buffer. and then write the output, which is stored also on an unsigned char buffer, to an output file.

Comment: Your comments are also contradictory: What is it? 32 characters, each "0" or "1", on a line, in a *text* file ... or *binary* data??

Comment: Hi @DanielJour, can you kindly tell me what is not clear about the post so I can make it better?. my data is 2's complement binary numbers stored in a text file. so, each line in the data file is a 32 bit binary number. there are 2048 numbers (lines) in total. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bits are clearly written as ASCII: you’ll want to read them formatted line by line and convert them to you `unsigned char`s by decoding them individually. For example:

```
for (std::string line; getline(in, line); ) {
    if (!std::all_of(line.begin(), line.end(),
                     [](char c){ return c == ‘0’ || c == ‘1’; })) {
        // deal with unexpected line
        continue;
    }
    for (int offset = 0; offset + 8 <= line.size(); offset += 8) {
        unsigned char c = std::bitset<8>(line.substr(offset, 8)).value();
        // do something with c
    }
}
```

The declarations you wondered about are primarily a display of not understanding C++: there is no place in C++ to define constants using `#define`. The semantic of the number clearly depends on how it is being used. As it is used on the line just following it it should be straight forward to determine what it is used for. Of course, there is also little place in C++ for fixed size arrays...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! yes in fact I don't know much about C++ and honestly your reply is far advanced from my basic understanding. I hope you can simplify your reply and any further comments to a language I can understand : )  I didn't 
 fully understand the code you mentioned but I think the second for loop will update c with new values on every iteration. what I want to do is, reading the numbers input file and store them in one array, so and every iteration I need to add numbers to the array rather than overwrite the old data. Thanks again and I hope to lean more from you!

Comment: Also, your code assuming that I have all the data in a string, right? how do I read the data properly from the file to the string?

Comment: The comment about not understanding C++ referred to your teacher as you wouldn’t have written the code to with. My code reads a line of text in each iteration of the outer loop and produces an `unsigned char` with each iteration if the inner loop. Distributing these into an array just amounts to assigning them to consecutive elements of the array. ... and I don’t know how to make the code simpler: it just uses the idiomatic approaches to the different subtasks needed.

Comment: So does the code add values to the array or overwrite the old data? thanks

Comment: The code I posted does neither: it hold the currently produced value in a variable which will be out of scope at the end of the iteration. You’ll need to stick its value into a suitable location in an array if that’s what you want to do. However, I’m not in the business of providing ready solutions to homework assignments: the answer is just dropping relevant entry points.

Comment: I have provided some solutions that I found on the internet and clearly showed the output for each method I applied, so simply I'm not asking for solving my homework! there is no homework here anyway! the whole point of the post is how to read these binary numbers from a text file properly and some comments about the sizes. my comments clearly show that I want to learn as well as solve my problem. I have also tried the following code and it did not work:

Comment: while (!f_in.eof()) {
 f_in >> char1;
 str1.append(char1);
}
 copy(str1.begin(), str1.end(), buf);
 buf[str1.length()] = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < Buff_size; i++) {
  cout << buf[i];
 }
That is why I'm asking for more explanations as I want to learn, not just applying the  code and move on.

Comment: I keep explaining since at least 20 years why `while (!in.eof())` is fundamentally wrong. Aside from that your solution doesn’t work because you are reading characters you haven’t initialized: you should either stick with tracking the length or using the sentinel (the C++ approach js to track the size, most likely through a suitable class). You could read what `getline()` and `bitset` do, e.g., on [cppreference.com](http://copreference.com): there is no need to just blindly copy the solution but understand how it works.

Comment: Based on what you write it seems necessary to convert the bits into a sequence of bytes, where groups of 8 bits form one byte: that’s what my code does except that it only produces the bytes which need to be stored in an array.